# How scan/find routers that not use the blue wan port?

Tags: router

In my network, there are 1 modem (DHCP enabled) that distribute the IP's for all the devices and computers. This modem is plugged to a big switch.

Additionally, there are several Wireless TP-LINK WR741ND routers in this network. I disabled DHCP in all and only use the LAN ports (the blue wan port is not used). They work ok, but

I want to know how I can access the admin setup of these routers from another computer, because aparently, there's no IP assigned to these routers.

I executed advanced ip scanner but none of these tp-link routers show up.

I looked in the manual and it seems the device only appears if used the blue wan port, but I must use only the LAN ports for them act as a switch with wireless.

Thanks.

Comment: So, your manual tells you that you cannot do this, but you want to do it anyway. I... claim the answer is most likely what the manual states. You can't do this.

Comment: the manual doesnt say this explicitly, I came to this conclusion because in there says to plug in the blue port for "standard" use.

Comment: how did you originally configured your network? How are these routers connected to your modem? is your modem a router as well?

Comment: they are plugged normally in the big switch that is plugged in the modem. The modem is DHCP enabled

Comment: I sort of disagree with everyone else so far - Per the manual, you can assign a LAN IP address on this router. You probably just need to remove it from the current network, connect a machine to it that can communicate within its default subnet (anything in 192.168.0.0 /24 except .1 and .255), try to open 192.168.0.1, disable DHCP, and then give it a static IP address for your LAN. I've gotten various routers to essentially become switches with interfaces this way....

Answer (score 0):

There is no IP address to change your routers as they are acting as network repeaters, not switches. In other words, they are just mirroring the data sent to your initial router and acting as extra ports for your first router and will share exactly the same IP address and MAC address as your initial router.

You have to use the WAN port as that is the only port in which they actually have an IP address, to all other ports they are only relaying messages and will respond to ANY message from ANY IP address by passing that IP and data to your master router.

Comment: First of all, it's entirely possible for hubs/switches to have assigned IP addresses - The physical ports and underlying function of the device really have nothing to do with this capability. Secondly you are confusing the differences between a repeater/hub, a switch, and a router. "...share exactly the same IP address and MAC address as your initial router" is also completely wrong.